# Puzzle - Snow Day Event

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

*Daisy, Delilah, Donny, and Duke* have each decided to participate in the snowperson building event.

In decorating their snowperson, each of them has chosen a different colour of the scarf from purple,
red, green, or blue. In addition, they have chosen one accessory from a top hat, earmuffs,
flower, or carrot nose.

*Daisy, Delilah, Donny, and Duke* have all chosen to give their snowpeople coal buttons.
However, each person has decided to give their snowperson a different number of buttons. One
snowperson has 2 buttons, one has 3 buttons, one has 4 buttons and one has 5 buttons.

Using the following clues, determine the combination of accessories and buttons that each
a person used to create their snowperson.

1. The snowperson built by Daisy, who is wearing the top hat, has one fewer button than
   the snowperson wearing the red scarf, but one more button than the snowperson with the
   carrot nose.
2. The snowperson wearing the blue scarf, who is also wearing earmuffs, has two fewer
   buttons than the snowperson wearing the green scarf.
3. The snowperson wearing the purple scarf has one more button than the snowperson built
   by Delilah.
4. The snowperson built by Duke is wearing the flower

You may find the table below helpful when solving this puzzle

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Final solution

> Daisy's snowperson has a top hat, green scarf, 4 buttons.
>  Delilah's snowperson has earmuffs, blue scarf, 2 buttons.
>  Donny's snowperson has a carrot nose, purple scarf, 3 buttons.
>  Duke's snowperson has a flower, red scarf, 5 buttons.

### Step-by-step solution

Just using directly the information given (ignoring more/less buttons for the moment, as we'll come back to that later, but using the information that more/less means *not the same*):

> [image: first pass - easy info]

(In the pictures I'm using red fill for no and green fill for yes, just to make it easy for myself when filling the grid.)

Then we know

> red = flower, therefore red = Duke. Also, using top-hat = Daisy and blue = earmuffs, we know Daisy =/= blue.

Now let's start using the information about number of buttons:

- > (Daisy = top-hat) has ONE FEWER than (Duke = flower = red) and ONE MORE than (carrot-nose). So (Daisy = top-hat) can't be 2 or 5, (Duke = flower = red) can't be 2, and (carrot-nose) can't be 5.
- > (blue = earmuffs) has TWO FEWER than (green). So the former can't be 4 or 5, and the latter can't be 2 or 3.
- > (purple) has ONE MORE than (Delilah). So the former can't be 2 and the latter can't be 5.

Now we have:

> [image: second pass - using all info]

It's now clear to see that

> flower = 5 and blue = 2, therefore blue = earmuffs = 2. So top-hat and carrot-nose must be 3 and 4 in some order, and we know from the first clue that Daisy = top-hat = 4 and carrot-nose = 3, which gives red = 5.
>
>  [image: third pass - after more deductions]

Now it's clear that

> purple = 3 and green = 4, and by the third clue that means Delilah = 2, therefore Delilah = blue = earmuffs = 2. Then by elimination Donny = carrot-nose, so Donny = carrot-nose = 3. The rest follows easily.
>
>  [image: fully filled grid]